# Including the same header files in a self-defined function again, which are already included in the main programm?

Tags: c, function, header-files, definition

Should I include the same header files, in the header file for that particular function or the function definition file, if I have included them already in the main program (the caller)?

For example:

```
/* Text of main programm */
#include <stdlib.h>                    /* Including the headers first */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <function.h>

int function(void);

int main (void)
{
     /* stdio.h is needed in main with f.e.
     printf("Let us using function!); */
     function();
     return(0);
}
_____________________________________________________________________

/* Headerfile for function ("function.h") */
/*
#include <stdlib.h>                Should I include the headers again here? 
#include <stdio.h> 
*/

int function (void);
_____________________________________________________________________

/* Definition of function ("function.c")*/

/*
#include <stdlib.h>                Should I include the headers again here? 
#include <stdio.h> 
*/

int function (void)
{
     printf("You know it right, baby!\n");
}
```

And what about if I want to use a special header and its function(s) in a self-defined function, but not need it in the main program?

I use C but want to use C++ in the future. If any difference between the answers for each of those is relevant for use, please mention it.

Thank you very much for your answers.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. You should post code examples of what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proper practice is:

- Each source file or header file should include header files that declare any identifier it is using.
- Each source file should include “its own” header file, that is, the header file that declares every external identifier the source file defines.

The reason for the former is to inform the compiler about the identifiers being used. This gives the compiler information it needs to compile the program correctly.

The reason for the latter is to ensure that the declarations match the definitions. By including the header file in the source file, the compiler sees both the declaration and the definition during the same compilation, so it can produce an error message if the declaration is incompatible with the definition.

It is **possible** to declare a function by putting its declaration explicitly in the source file where it is used instead of in a header, but this is bad practice because errors can arise due to typing mistakes or changes that are made in one file and not another.

It is not necessary to include header files that declare identifiers not used by a source file, even if those identifiers are used by other files. In your example with `function.c`, `function.c` does not need to include `<stdio.h>` if it is not using any identifier from `<stdio.h>`. The fact that `main.c` does use `<stdio.h>` is irrelevant, because, when the compiler is compiling `function.c`, that is separate from `main.c`.

Answer (score 3):

Per your example, you should have a header file for `function` and it should be included by both source files. You want to include `function.h` in `function.c` so that you don't forget to change the header file if for some reason you need to change the signature of `function()` like adding a parameter or changing the return type.

main.c

```
// Include any standard headers needed here
#include <stdio.h>
#include "function.h"

int main (void)
{
    printf("Calling function()");
    function();
    return(0);
}
```

function.h

```
#ifndef _FUNCTION_H_
#define _FUNCTION_H_

// Include only those headers that this header file needs

int function(void);

#endif
```

function.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "function.h"

int function (void)
{
    printf("Hello\n");
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. So, in result, it means i have to include the headers again for each function, which need them.  I can not just include `stdio.h` and `stdlib.h` in main (if i need them there) and do not include them in any function() (assuming i need functions of them there), right?

Comment: Any `.c` file that will be calling `function()` needs to include `function.h`. Header files should only include other header files if they need information from those files in order to compile.

Comment: '@Jim Rhodes' Yes, that is what i understood. But besides of the calling of function(): What if i need functions of `stdio.h` inside `main` AND in `function()`? Do i have to include the headerfile `stdio.h` in each of those separated or is there an "invisible understanding" connection between `main`and `function` that give me the opportunity to not include the same header again, if i already included `stdio.h`in `main`?

Comment: @RobertS there is no magic invisible super understanding. You need an include for every token of your program, when that token is not a primitive C or is not defined by the file itself.

Comment: @RobertS, yes, if main.c calls functions defined in stdio.h, it must include stdio.h. When compiling main.c, the compiler will not look at what is being included by function.c..

Answer (score 1):

No, you should include, in file F, only those files which are needed for what you declare or refer (use) in file F.

In other words, in your main you don't need stdio.h and stdlib.h, because your main does not use them. But you need function.h because you will use function().

Moreover, in your main, you declare:

```
int function(void);
```

but the same declaration is already in function.h which you did previously #include.

In your example, if you instead declare directly the correct prototype of function(), then you don't need anymore to include function.h!

---

On the other hand, correctly (and simple) formed header files could *often* be included even if they are useless or redundant. They slow down the compilation, but don't have harmful effects.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Where should i include the stdio.h header-file into? Into the function´s definition file or its header-file, or even both?
And what if i would really need functions of stdio.h in the main programm?

Comment: You should #include where it is needed. Given that in function.h you do not refer to anything concerning stdio.h or stdlib.h, then you should not include them there. But instead, in function.c, you use printf(), so you must include stdio.h.

Answer (score 0):

No. If your main (or any function in the current translation unit) calls a function named `function`, you should include a header declaring `function`, but you do not need to include the headers that the translation unit defining `function` includes unless you also use them.

```
#include "function.h" 
//^ this should be "-quoted not <-quoted because it's not a system header
//int funtion(void); //this declaration is redundant
//#include <stdio.h> isn't needed here because you're not directly calling
//functions from stdio

int main (void)
{
     function();
     return(0);
}
```

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. Should i include the stdio.h file inside of the definition of function() or in its header-file then or in both?

Comment: Preferably only in `function.c` and not in `function.h`.

Comment: @RobertS Then include them in each c file. While including them in function.h would do the job more DRYily, it would also force other users of functio.h to implicitly include stdio.h, which would slightly increase their compilation time and polute their namespace with stdio items that they might want to be locally overriding (such overriding would probably be a bad idea but anyway...).

Comment: What if i need `stdio.h` and `stdlib.h` (just as an example) in `main()` and in `function()`? Do i need to include these headers in main.c AND in function.c or would the compiler make a bridge of saying you do not need to include them again, its already included because of the function´s subordinate state in comparison to main?

Comment: @RobertS You need to include them again. C compilers consider each C file separately (which BTW allows separate compilation).